# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Entity ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, metadata, single-sign-on, saml

For the SSO setup for SFMC Exact Target, where to find the Entity id. Followed this document to create SSO meta data https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_create_salesforce_saml_key.htm&type=5 but how to find the Entity ID? There is no information in Help.Salesforce that I could find. In other forums, they suggested using https://sp.exacttarget.com/shibboleth-sp but this did not help. Can anyone advise on how to get the Entity ID for the SSO setup?

Regards

Comment: Please advise if there is a standard entity I'd for exact target marketing cloud.

Answer (score 1):

When contacting salesforce to enable sso in MC using a third party idp, they sent us this link that has details of mc metadafile. If yiu click on the metadafile in the link identity id is https://sp.exacttarget.com/shibboleth-sp. This is the entity id we entered in our third party idp.